# base_url().'assets/ works giving css/images/js location but js is not running in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, css, codeigniter

I have this structure

```
/www
    /code_igniter
        /application
        /assets
            +img
            +css
            +js
        /controllers
        /system
```

I load two views in controller:

```
class Control extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');  

    }
     public function index()
    {
         $this->load->view('header');
     $this->load->view('body');
    }

}
```

In header view I do:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>css/stile.css' />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>css/chosen.css' />

<script src="<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/logic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

body has pure html.

when I see source code of generated view It can find the js, css and images but for some strange reason it is not executing the js as if it would not find them...

I tested locally and it  works!!

To try to reproduce error I renamed js folfer and yeah, it shows the same result as when testing on server, i then rename it to js and works locally but not in server...

Do you know what could be causing this? Is driving me crazy

Could it be a crach between jquery.min.js ?  It is like is not running anything,

I also find this issue I am loading http://rhinoslider.com/ in a script in header view

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
           alert("a");
       $('#slider').rhinoslider({
        controlsPlayPause: false,
                showControls: 'always',
                showBullets: 'always',
                controlsMousewheel: false,                   
        slidePrevDirection: 'toRight',
        slideNextDirection: 'toLeft'
            });


           alert("b");          
        $(".rhino-prev").hide();                
        $('.rhino-next').after('<a class="form-submit" href="#" >Next</a>');
                $(".rhino-next").hide();
      alert("c");       


        });
```

And I am only receiving alert a message, it is not executing or [loading rhino slider](http://rhinoslider.com/) why could it be ?

Comment: Probably something to do with htaccess. Better check if mod_rewrite is enabled on server

Comment: Where is your `index.php` file in the structure. Is it outside the codeigniter directory?

Comment: You can recheck the case of the file name, whether it is mixed of lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: @SeainMalkin `index.php` is inside `code_igniter/` folder, (did you mean codeigniter index right?)

Comment: If I put `http://www.server.com/code_igniter/index.php` i get the welcome message

Comment: Do the urls for the scripts appear to be correct if you inspect the source of the page?

Comment: My guess is your `base_url` is not set correctly in `config.php`

Comment: @Jeemusu yes they appear correctly when I see source code of view, even I click on link And get to source of css or js, I think maybe the jquery is corrupted or maybe craching with something  that codeigniters has as default?

Comment: @SeainMalkin I revisited and it seems ok, maybe a problem with default index? or something?

Comment: I even add this in config.php `$config['assets'] = $config['base_url'] . 'assets/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>css/stile.css' />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>css/chosen.css' />

  <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/'?>js/logic.js" type="text/javascript">
```

or **set**

```
 short_open_tag = On
```

in **php.ini** file in order to make short tag working on you localhost

hope it will help!